# Easiest way to import image file to OpenGL ES 2.0 cross platform

Tags: image, opengl-es-2.0

I am learning to use OpenGL ES 2.0 by using MoSync to write cross platform C code. I have already managed to draw basic shapes such as a triangle, square and circle so the next stage is to draw some text to the screen. After reading various books, tutorials and forum posts I realise I have to create a texture atlas bitmap.

I have a file with the text I want to use, i.e 0-9 a-z image file. Before I can upload and bind it to a texture object I first need to upload the image to OpenGL. Various tutorials use UIImage or BitmapFactory to upload the image but I cannot use these as MoSync does not contain their header files. Could anyone suggest a way to load my image file to OPenGL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using maOpenGLTexImage(MAHandle image), which works exactly as glTexImage2D() but it uses an image resource instead and figures out pixel formats etc.

Answer (score 0):

To use MoSync on the Android platform you are probably going to have to make a native library for MoSync and your OpenGL ES code in C++.  Most OpenGL ES projects on Android are done in native code for many reasons which are detailed in this article:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/porting-opengl-games-to-android-on-intel-atom-processors-part-1/